# More than two views side by side in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have three `TextView's` in a `RelativeLayout` and I'm trying to position them side by side.

What I expect to get is :

```
|Text THREE | Text ONE | Text TWO|
```

Instead what I get is :

```
| Text ONE | Text TWO |
```

My xml code is :

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_test"
    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:text="Text ONE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:text="Text TWO"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t3"
        android:text="Text THREE"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what happens when you add to `t1` the following : `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` ?

Comment: it works!! What I did wrong ?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri how can I apply this logic to more than 3 views? ( it *has* to be in a relativelayout container )

Comment: Your view was getting drawn however was hidden since th `t1` started drawing from the left by default.

Comment: care to mention why it _has_ to be in a relative layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**:

You can add to the following to `t1`:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Basically what we are trying to do it to bring the `TextView` `t1` in the centre so that the one at the left and the right can be seen. Similarly you can apply the concept if you have even more `TextViews`.

**Method 2**:

The other way is to align the first one at the left most using `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and the use the `android:layout_toRightOf=""` for all the subsequent `TextView`'s.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a `LinearLayout` to get that.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="T1"/>
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="T2"/>
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="T3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

you didn't say if you want the `TextView`s to stretch to fit equally. to do that, you'd make their `width` 0dp and their `weight` equal 1.

you can use `RelativeLayout` but it's overkill for what you are doing.